# reverse doubly linked list by recursive way not iterate in python

Tags: python-3.x, doubly-linked-list

How I write the reverse function by recursive for double linkedlist. I have refer the questions reverse double linked list using recursion and rewrite in python but it brings me to infinite loop so I rewrite the logic but I kind of lost prev point

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, prev=None, nxt=None):
        self.val = data
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = nxt


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head

    def print_list(self):
        cur = self.head
        while cur is not None:
            print(cur.val)
            cur = cur.next

    def reverse(self):
        if self.head is None or self.head.next is None: return self.head
        cur = self.head
        def reverse_node(node):
            if node is None: return
            if node.next is None:
                node.prev = None
                return node
            new_head = reverse_node(node.next)
            new_node = node.next
            tmp = new_node.next
            new_node.prev = tmp
            new_node.next = node
            node.next = None
            return new_head
        self.head = reverse_node(cur)

a = Node(1, prev=None)
b = Node(2, prev=a)
c = Node(3, prev=b)
d = Node(4, prev=c)
a.next = b
b.next = c
c.next = d
dll = DoublyLinkedList(a)
dll.print_list()
dll.reverse()
dll.print_list()
```

Comment: By changing `dll.reverse()` to `dll.reverse_recursive()` I seem to get it to work.  The list prints backwards and the head points to the element with `val=4`.  Could you describe more what is unwanted with what your code is doing?

Comment: thank you reverse to reverse is my typo. after `self.head = head` and actually i think i just fix my code by rewriting the logic for reverse function. I will delete the post

Answer (score 0):

All I have done is add some printouts at the end to see what is where.  It looks to me as though your code does what you expect of it.  After the `reverse()` function the head seems to clearly point to `d` instead of `a`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, prev=None, nxt=None):
        self.val = data
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = nxt


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head

    def print_list(self):
        cur = self.head
        while cur is not None:
            print(cur.val)
            cur = cur.next

    def reverse(self):
        if self.head is None or self.head.next is None: return
        cur = self.head

        def reverse_node(node):
            if node is None: return node
            node.next, node.prev = node.prev, node.next
            if node.prev is None: return node
            return reverse_node(node.prev)

        self.head = reverse_node(cur)

a = Node(1, prev=None)
b = Node(2, prev=a)
c = Node(3, prev=b)
d = Node(4, prev=c)
a.next = b
b.next = c
c.next = d
dll = DoublyLinkedList(a)
print("Head: ",dll.head.val)
dll.print_list()
dll.reverse()
print()
print("Head: ",dll.head.val)
dll.print_list()
print("Is the head at a? ",dll.head is a)
print("Is the head at d? ",dll.head is d)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Head:  1
1
2
3
4

Head:  4
4
3
2
1
Is the head at a?  False
Is the head at d?  True
```

Comment: cool, thank you. I just update my original post. so my original code does not really work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I will just post my rewrite reverse logic here and it seems works now. free free to comment it

```
    def reverse(self):
        if self.head is None or self.head.next is None: return
        cur = self.head

        def reverse_node(node):
            if node is None: return node
            node.next, node.prev = node.prev, node.next
            if node.prev is None: return node
            return reverse_node(node.prev)
        self.head = reverse_node(cur)
```